# How to exclude loss computation on certain tensors in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to do pose-conditioned face generation. The idea is to use an auto-encoding network that takes an image as an input and a conditional vector containing the pose information, such that the generated image is conditioned on the conditional vector.

For computing the loss using MSE, I am generating the face landmarks of the predicted image using a face-landmark detection library. Unfortunately, during the early epochs, the network produces garble and the face-landmark detection library returns `None` instead of an expected tensor of the form `256 x 256 x 3` where a pixel value indicates the presence of a landmark.

What I would like to do is to ignore computing the loss when no face has been detected.

Example -- assume that my batch is of the form -> `10 x 256 x 256 x 3`, where 10 is the `batch_size` and `256x256` is the dimension of the image with `3` channels. For the predictions, let's assume that no landmarks could be generated for 3 images in the batch. I could set the prediction tensor for which no face landmarks could be generated to `NaN` values and the predicted landmarks would have the form - `10 x 256 x 256 x 3`. In my MSE loss function, I would like to ignore gradient computation originating from tensor containing the `NaN` values. To make life simple, I want to ignore those individual 3 tensors that had all `NaN` values.

Any help would be appreciated. I have a backup with a `for` loop but that is sub-optimal.

This is some sample code -

```
import numpy as np
import torch
from torchvision import transforms
import random

transform = transforms.Compose(
        [
            transforms.ToPILImage(),
            transforms.CenterCrop(size),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
        ]
    )

image_tensors = torch.randn(10, 3, 256, 256)
tensor_meshes = list()
for image_tensor in image_tensors:
    image_array = image_tensor.detach().cpu().numpy()

    image_landmarks = generate_mesh_from_image(image_array) # returns either None or landmark image of dimension -> 3 x 256 x 256

    if image_landmarks is None:
        image_landmarks = np.empty(3, 256, 256) # creates np matrix with Nan values

    # convert to tensor
    landmark_tensor = transform(image_landmarks) 

    tensor_meshes.append(landmark_tensor)

# convert tensor_meshes to a torch tensor of dimension -> 10 x 3 x 256 x 256
## SAMPLE CODE ##

# some dummy code to simulate generating landmark images
def generate_mesh_from_image(image_array):
    rand = random.randint(0, 1)
    if rand == 0:
        return None
    else:
        return np.random.randn(3, 256, 256)
```

The loss now needs to be computed between the prediction tensor (10 x 3 x 256 x 256) and the ground truth tensor (10 x 3 x 256 x 256). However, the prediction tensor contains some tensor elements that have all NaN values which I would like ignore during the loss computation.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code for us to start from? Having `NaN` values, does it mean the output tensor has `NaN` tensor values for batch elements with no landmarks?

Comment: Hi @Ivan thank you for your reply. I have added some dummy code to navigate. I am explicitly setting the individual tensor element (essentially 3x256x256) to NaN values so that it's treated as a usual tensor. However, I would like that tensor to be excluded in the loss computation step from the batch.

Comment: I am confused as to how your model outputs data. You said the output is shaped 10x3x256x256, in that case how are the images with no landmarks represented inside that batch?

Comment: Consider that the input images are of dimension 10x3x256x256. The model generates an image, therefore, the output shape would be 10x3x256x256 as well. I am running a landmark detection code on top of the predicted images. Now, the landmark detection code takes an image of dimension 3x256x256 as input and returns the image of the same dimension if landmarks were detected, otherwise, the method returns None. I need to compute the loss between these images and the ground-truth landmark images which are again of dimension 3x256x256. Inside the batch their dimension is 10x3x256x256.

Comment: Now, there are image predictions that are so bad, that no landmarks could be generated for those images. In that case, the landmark detection model would just return None. Now, to compute the loss, I take the L1 distance between the predicted landmarks and the ground-truth landmarks both of dimensions 10x3x256x256. In cases, where the predicted landmarks are None, I need my loss function to ignore those tensors (in other words, not compute their gradients). I thought one way I could do it was set these tensors to NaN and exclude them by specifying a sentinel value in the loss function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a mask containing ones for images with landmarks and zeros for those without. Then simply compute the loss on the whole batch and apply the mask afterwards, before performing back propagation.

Comment: How do I apply the mask afterwards? If I calculate the loss directly using MSE, it just gives me one value.

Comment: I see, you should set the `reduction` argument of your `nn.MSELoss` to `"none"` which will prevent it from reducing it by averaging over batch elements.